# Submitting form by hitting enter on keyboard

Tags: php, javascript

Currently my team has this `(onKeyPress="keyPress(event))` defined for each field in a form. So if i have 20 fields then it is defined 20 times. I am wondering if it is possible to define this at the form level rather than field so we only define it one and not 20 times?

Using PHP codeignitor.

Comment: This should be automatic for html forms, and doesn't need javascript event handlers.

Comment: @digitalFresh, this only happens with input, not with textarea.

Comment: In most browsers if you are editing a <input type="text"> then pressing enter submits the form anyway.

Comment: Except for textareas, it's default behavior...

Comment: You could ID (put an id) on each form.

Comment: Hmmm, if is not default. When they created the login and signup form i was pressing enter in IE, firefox and Chrome and nothing happened until he added this code in?

Comment: @JonnyQ The automatic submission only happens when the fields are in a `<form>` element. If your form is in a form element, it should happen unless stopped by a handler.

Answer (score 2):

Define the event for the whole `<form>`. Then use `event.target` to find a particular form element and do something with it.

- A form element key-press event is generated and passed to the `<form>` element for handling.
- No handler is directly bound to the element, so the event bubbles up the DOM tree to the `<form>`.
- Here you test if the `event.target` matches the said element.
- If a matching element is found, the `<form>` handler is called on it

Comment: More on event bubbling:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have jquery, you can bind it to all the input fields at once...

```
$('input').bind('keypress', function (e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            //do stuff
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's think your form is like below

```
<form id="my_form" method="post">
    [...]
</form>
```

Then you can submit with JS like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("keypress", function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
           $('#my_form').submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```